# Find limit $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x - (\sin x)^{\sin x}}{1 - \sin x + \ln(\sin x)}$

Tags: limits

Find the limit of $$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x - (\sin x)^{\sin x}}{1 - \sin x + \ln(\sin x)}.$$

Please help, D L rule does not help

Comment: What is DL rule?

Comment: @EricAuld L'Hôspital rule

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two applications of L'Hospital's Rule will do it. Note that it is enough to find 
$$\lim_{t\to 1} \frac{t-t^t}{1-t+\ln t}.$$
Differentiate top and bottom. On top we get
$$1-(1+\ln t)t^t.\tag{1}$$
At the bottom we get
$$-1+\frac{1}{t}.\tag{2}$$
Multiply both (1) and (2) by $t$, and use L'Hospital's Rule again.

Comment: Two applications, yes but after adopting your change. Otherwise, four ! If you want fun, keep the original formula and start the derivations ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution is what proposed André Nicolas. If you do not do it this way, you would need to apply L'Hospital's rule **four** times. Taking these derivatives would be a pure nightmare (please, do not try !) and after four derivations, you would see that the limit of the numerator is -6 and the limit of the denominator is -3. Finally, your limit will be 2.

You told that you do not know Taylor series. Let me briefly explain that to you : it is a way to approximate a function around a given point (something as the tangent at the very first order). When they will teach that topic, give a lot of attention since it is a very powerful tool you will use very often later in your studies. For illustration purposes, I built the expansion of your function : close to x = Pi/2, the function is very close to
2 - 7 (x - Pi/2)^2 / 6

Answer (score 0):

Expanding in Taylor series should help. Use $O$ notation to make it simpler. Do you know how to do these things?

Comment: Don't know Taylor series. Only D L Hopital rule

Comment: @user2369284 Put down what you tried for L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: I just differentiated the whole thing but that does not lead me anywhere.

Comment: @user2369284. You only did it once !

Answer (score 0):

Let sinx=t.Thus,limit changes to t->1.then apply DL rule twice to get the answer as 2.